# How to get the value from DataGrid's SelectedItem?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm, prism

In my project i have one Datagrid and i bind the following fields that are listed below.

```
CustomerID, Name, Email.
```

I have the Entity named `WS_Customer`. i have put one button control for all row in datagrid.If i click the button means the i need to get the `CustomerID` value.
How to get it.

If i put like this means,

```
WS_Customer  getid=(WS_Customer)DG.SelectedItem;
```

getidshows null..
How i got the value?

Comment: are you trying to debug this? is DG.SelectedItem == null?

Comment: no i'm not trying to debug this... If i click the button means i need to get the value of the ID in the Entity Called "WS_Customer"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using MVVM... and you DataGrid is bound to a collection of the WS_Customer objects you can put a property in your view model that you can bind to the SelectedItem property of the DataGrid. Keep in mind the row must be selected for the SelectedItem property to have a value.

In xaml:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWS_Customer}" />
```

In viewModel:

```
public WS_Customer SelectedWS_Customer
{          

  get
  {
      return _selectedWS_Customer; //private variable
  }
  set
  {
       _selectedWS_Customer = value;
  }
}
```